# PDO fetchColumn not returning correct row count

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

There are 101 records in `document_list` table for the `user_id` 10, but `$num_rows` return only 12 records count. I am using [MariaDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB) database.

Please help me to make this work correctly.

How `fetchColumn()` works? I really can't understand this, *Returns a single column from the next row of a result set or FALSE if there are no more rows.*

Thanks in advance.

```
$user_id = 10;
$bind_values = array(
    ':user_id' => $user_id,
);
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM document_list WHERE user_id=:user_id";
function SelectRowCounts($caller_file,$database_name,$query,$bind_values)
{
    $query_exe = $this->db_connection->$database_name();
    $query_fetch_data = $query;
    try
    {
        $data = $query_exe->prepare($query_fetch_data);
        $data->execute($bind_values);
        return $num_rows = $data->fetchColumn();
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
        ....
        ....
```

Comment: Since this happens here on SO _every_ other day: Double/tripple check your data source; you're most likely using a different database.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps dealing with boolean columns? See manual: http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

To check if your query is returning the correct data you can change it to `"SELECT * FROM document_list"` and then call `$data->rowCount()` - this should return 101, too.